# ios 8 keyboard issue when predictive is set on

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing a chat application which has textview and other buttons placed on a view. I have an issue with iOS8 keyboard when predictive is set on.
When predictive is off it is working fine but it is set on my view in which textview and other buttons are placed is displaces.

I added NSNotification for KeyboardWillShow and KeyboardWillHide in viewDidLoad.

viewDummy is a view where textview and other buttons are added

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect kKeyBoardFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{

        CGRect frame = viewDummy.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= kbSize.height;
        viewDummy.frame = frame;


        frame = bubbleTable.frame;
        frame.size.height -= kbSize.height;
        bubbleTable.frame = frame;
    }];
}


-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note{

    NSDictionary* info = [note userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{

        CGRect frame = viewDummy.frame;
        frame.origin.y += kbSize.height;
        viewDummy.frame = frame;

        frame = bubbleTable.frame;
        frame.size.height += kbSize.height;
        bubbleTable.frame = frame;
    }];

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the view misplaced if you dismiss the keyboard and show it again? There're `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` which post a notification when turning predictive input on/off. Register for those notifications might help you.

Answer (score 0):

- What i did to get rid of this issue was:
- adjusted kbSize.height manually according to difference.
- the difference was of height i.e 44 in my case.
- so what i did was frame.origin.y += kbSize.height + 44 or 
  frame.origin.y -= kbSize.height + 44, i think this might help you.